# Library overwrites signal handler, but I need to clean up on CTRL+C

Tags: c++, signals

I write a terminal application that uses a device controlled by a poorly designed library that overwrites `SIGINT` (CTRL+C). My goal is to use the device correctly using that library, but I want to be able to close my application nicely with some cleaning up. (Otherwise, I would not follow the protocol of other devices I connect to and could not re-connect when running the program again.)

Here is what I tried:

```
std::atomic< bool > globalQuit(false);

void signalHandler(int signal)
{
    globalQuit = true;
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    badLibraryCall();
    while (!globalQuit)
    {
        badLibraryCall();
    }
    doCleanUp();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I hit CTRL+C, a different signalHandler that is registered in `badLibraryCall` is called and exits. No nice `doCleanUp` is done.

Comment: @mike.dld, is corrected. I played around with different signals as a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you are out of luck unless you play really dirty tricks like [using LD_PRELOAD](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/) to override `signal` or `sigaction` behavior when you can reasonably infer that you're inside in the bad library.

However, you *might* be able to run `badLibraryCall` in a separate process, a child of your main process.  Then your trapping of SIGINT could reap it, killing as needed, and perform whatever cleanup you need to do.